# JQuery not working, possible source error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Notepad++ and when I save and run this code in the browser the Jquery does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Result</title
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        $("div").fadeout('slow');
    });
}); 
</script>
        <div></div>  
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #FA6900;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: add some text in the div & recheck

Comment: Also there is an extra closing `</script>` tag after your `div` and the function is `fadeOut()` not `fadeout()` JS is case sensitive

Comment: Tried and still nothing.

Comment: deleted extra script tag, still nothing.

Comment: change the fadeout name like I edited my comment

Comment: <title> tag also not closed.

Comment: close your `title` tag

Comment: Capitilized fadeout, still nothing.

Comment: Title tag not being closed did it. thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `fadeout` with `fadeOut`

EDIT: As comments suggested, your title tag needs to be closed too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").click(function() {
    $("div").fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FA6900;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Also you can replace the inner `$(div)` with `$(this)` if you just want the clicked div to fadeout

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FA6900;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```